# Google Maps API Parameters

Tags: python, google-maps, url, python-requests

I'm sure this is an obvious mistake, but does anyone know why this code isn't working? Am I using the python requests library incorrectly?

```
import requests

header =  {'Content-Type ': 'application/json'}
body = {
  "api_key": REDACTED,
  "size": "200x200",
  }

response = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap", headers = header, json = body)
data = response.content

print data
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to create an URL to a Google Map (with additional parameters I will set, such as lats/longs and markers).

Comment: What does the URL created by library look like?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap, so it's not getting the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - was setting my parameters incorrectly.

```
import requests
params = {'Content-Type ': 'application/json',  "api_key": REDACTED, "size": "200x200"}

response = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap", params = params)
data = response.url
print data
```